# Drone's Remote control not powering on!

Tags: rf, remote-control, drone

I am using bayangtoys X16 GPS drone.
I managed to solder the "alfa APA-M04 7 dBi gain RP-SMA directional panel antenna Wi-Fi" on the board, and it was working absolutely fine. Until, I put hot glue on the antenna's solder to make it more solid.

Since then , when I power on the remote the red light comes on for a second and beeps then it goes off. I removed the hot glue and still its doing same thing..

(That glue near the LED is factory set, it was there since the beginning)

1)I have checked for any short on the antenna's ground and main wire, there is no short there. I have checked the battery and power, and all looks good.
2) Battery are tested for voltage and working fine.
The board is receiving proper voltage from the battery, I tested the voltage on the board as well.

Could anyone help me out please!

Link to video explaining the issue [Video](https://vimeo.com/290456327)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: these two statements contradict each other ....`I put hot glue on the antenna's solder` and `That glue is factory set, it was there since the begining`

Comment: It seems likely to me that you have cracked one or more of the connections between the daughtercard and the main board while applying the hot glue. Try carefully reheating all of the solder joints where the two boards meet.

Comment: @jsotola : I mentioned about the glue because, I did not want you to confuse that glue with what I had put.

Comment: @DaveTweed : Those two boards do not have any soldering from the side I out hot glue.
If you see the PA chip, thats where it is soldered to the main board.

Comment: The little board sticks through a slot on the larger single-sided board. The solder joints are on the other side of the main board (duh!). If you flexed these joints at all while applying or removing the hot glue, you probably cracked some of them.

Comment: @DaveTweed I checked the daughterboard, and I also checked with volt meter for any shorting. There is proper voltage on the antenna's ground and main wire indicating that current is travelling from main board to that daughterboard

The power does not stay on for some strange reasons. Check my video.

Comment: @DaveTweed   That power LED is on the main board, and if you see the video, it goes off immediately.
Someone told me that it goes off after initializing the RF chip. But I am not too sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have just loaded critical RF tuning conductors with shunt capacitance of hot-glue and now it fails due to antenna impedance mismatch. They often use small pF values far less than a gob of glue.

The super hot comment implies either total Tx power reflected back or ESD damage from process handling.

Comment: That sounds most likley. I’ve corrected the capitalization.

Comment: So, may I know how should I fix this problem?
Just to give more understanding of the issue, the power light comes on if I leave the power button in off position for 10 seconds or more.
If I power it back on after 10 Sec, the light comes up, but if I immediately power it on after 1st time, then the light does not comes on.

Did you check the video link I posted?  That explains the issue

Comment: Insufficient info and details

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist 
I don't if this helps or not, but the power switch gets super hot if I leave it  switched on.

Comment: The video explains nothing of your rework except shows LEDs off and on as you describe near the conductors and small SMD parts that I describe. Super hot implies ESD damage. Or something faulty.